# Factorization in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am completely new to Mathematica and I need some help (sorry if it is trivial, but I haven't found the answer). I have this code

```
K[Q_, n_Integer] :=   Module[{z, x},    SymmetricReduction[
     SeriesCoefficient[
      Product[ComposeSeries[Series[Q[z], {z, 0, n}], 
        Series[x[i] z, {z, 0, n}]], {i, 1, n}], n], 
     Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}], Table[Subscript[c, i], {i, 1, n}]][[1]]]
```

Then I call this:

```
  K[ Sqrt[#]/Tanh[Sqrt[#]]&, 8] /. c->p
```

The output is a polynomial in p1, p2 ... p8 (in this case) with coefficients written as fractions (23412/7538293, for example). What should I do in order to output the numerator and denominator of each function in it's prime factorization (preferably factor out the common divisor of the denominator)?
Thank you!

Comment: you should ask on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: @agentp thank you! didn't know about that